# Use PowerShell to update a SharePoint list choice column with a random choice

Tags: list, sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I need to update all of the items in a list in SharePoint using PowerShell. The column I need to update [in each list item] is a choice column with 5 different choices. I need to randomly assign one of the choice options to each list item.

If possible, I would like to assign a probability for each one of these choices! (ie - Choice 1 = 30% chance, Choice 2 = 30% chance, Choice 3 = 30% chance, Choice 4 = 5% chance, Choice 5 = 5% chance)

I have started to build my script, but I'm not exactly sure how to handle the get-random section, or if I even use get random in this case.

Help is appreciated!!

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://weburl
$list = $web.Lists["Project Tasks Backup"] 
foreach ($item in $list.Items) 
{ 
  $item["Task Status"]  = $choices | Get-Random 
  $item.Update(); 
}
```

Thanks so much!

-Josh

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a random number between 1 - 5

```
$rand = New-Object  System.Random
$rand.next(1,6) # gets random number between 1 and 5
```

[Using System.Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)

Some other examples of powershell random-ness

http://poshcode.org/118

http://tfl09.blogspot.com/2007/01/random-numbers-in-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Get-Random meets your randomness requrirements, you can first create an array of choices, with the weighting you specified, like this:

```
$a = @('c1')*6 + @('c2')*6 + @('c3')*6 + @('c4','c5')
```

Then you can use Get-Random to randomly select an element from the array:

```
$selected = Get-Random -InputObject $a
```

Or, you can shuffle the array:

```
$shuffled = Get-Random -InputObject $a -Count $a.Length
```